# Version of Delve is too old for Go version 1.20.0 (maximum supported version 1.19)

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

When start debbugging session in GoLand I get this error:

> WARNING: undefined behavior - version of Delve is too old for Go version 1.20.0 (maximum supported version 1.19)

I reinstall it with JetBrains Toolbox and didn't work.
I uninstall it and install it manualy and didn't work!

The IDE maintainers say that GoLand didn't update delve when updating the IDE version in SOME CONDITIONS!

Comment: Have you tried installing a newer version of delve?

Comment: No, there is no doc on JetBrains to update it in GoLand. If you have a resource to do it please provide me with it.

Comment: Please download EAP version of GoLand (https://www.jetbrains.com/go/nextversion/). It contains the latest version of Delve.

Comment: Thanks But, it is stable?

Comment: It is in Beta right now, so pretty stable. Alternatively, you can update Delve using following workaround: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-14287/undefined-behavior-version-of-Delve-is-too-old-for-Go-version-1.20.0-maximum-supported-version-1.19#focus=Comments-27-6915232.0-0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was using GoLand 2022.3.2, recently 2022.3.3 was released and I update it to the latest version, and the issue was resolved.

I don't think it solves the problem entirely and I may hit it again in the future. So, I hope they fix it in a complete manner.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly install the latest version of delve based on the instructions here,
https://github.com/go-delve/delve/tree/master/Documentation/installation

```bash
# Install the latest release:
$ go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest
```

After installing the latest version of `dlv`, identify the path of the `dlv` executable file,

```bash
which dlv
# Output: /Users/<username>/go/bin/dlv
```

In your debug console check for the path that is used for running dlv
`/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.1/plugins/go/lib/dlv/macarm/dlv`

Goto to the above path and follow the below steps,

```bash
mv dlv dlv.old # If the dlv is present 
ln -s /Users/<username>/go/bin/dlv dlv
```

Now you can rerun the application and you should be able to get the debugger working.

Answer (score 2):

I found this workaround from the official issue.

1. Install dlv binary with go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest
2. Set the dlv.path=<path_to_dlv_executable> under Help > Edit Custom Properties
3. Restart GoLand

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue in this way:

go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest

(first make a copy of the original dlv.exe)

copy '%homepath%\go\bin\dlv.exe'  to 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\goland-2022.1.4.win\plugins\go\lib\dlv\windows\dlv.exe'
restart GolandIDE

Answer (score 0):

You can either install the latest version of goland or upgrade only the dlv. For the latter, download source code from [here](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/releases/tag/v1.20.1) and run `go install pathToYourDownloadedPackage/cmd/dlv`

Comment: Please read the post comments, there is no doc on JetBrains to update delve in GoLand.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Updating the Goland version solved my problem.

Make sure you've fully updated your IDE by following these commands: `Help -> Check for updates.`

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu, if you install goland by jetbrains toolbox, you can upgrade goland dlv with following commands:

```
go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest                     # download and compile latest version dlv
p=~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/goland/plugins/go/lib/dlv/linux # goland dlv binary location
$p/dlv version                                # check older version                                     
mv $p/dlv $p/dlv.old && mv $GOPATH/bin/dlv $p # move to upgrade
$p/dlv version                                # check newer version
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, and I have solved it by replacing the DLV bound to Goland with a 1.8.0 support Golang 1.16 DLV version.

1. download an older dlv version supporting your golang version, such as: my golang is 1.16 and dlv use this [delve1.8.0](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/releases/tag/v1.8.0)
2. complie dlv:

```
cd <downloadDir>/cmd/dlv 
go build
```

3. edit goland properties: `Help > Edit Custom Properities...`, and add

```
dlv.path=<yourPath>/cmd/dlv/dlv
```